# exist a comand to extract a part of a list and put it in the beging of the same list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, sorting

i and trying to do something like this:

```
list=[a,b,cow,c,d,elefant,f]
def find_between_tags(self,lst, start_tag, end_tag):#(1) this funtion take a sub list of the list between the start_tag and the end_tag
    start_index = lst.index(start_tag)#(1)
    end_index = lst.index(end_tag, start_index)#(1)
    return lst[start_index + 1: end_index]#(1)
#some command like
list=**up**(find_between_tags(list,cow,elefant))
print(list)
```

and the result of the operations that i am searching was

```
[cow,c,d,elefant,a,b,f]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You already found the indexes of the `start_tag` and `end_tag`, you now just need to use those indexes to formulate your resultant list.

```
lst = ['a','b','cow','c','d','elefant','f']

def find_between_tags(lst, start_tag, end_tag):

    start_index = lst.index(start_tag)
    end_index = lst.index(end_tag)
    return lst[start_index: end_index+1]+lst[0:start_index]+lst[end_index+1: len(lst)]

print(find_between_tags(lst, 'cow', 'elefant'))
#['cow', 'c', 'd', 'elefant', 'a', 'b', 'f']
```